# 1/3 Columns With Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a custom grid with Twitter Bootstrap 2.0, and I'm trying to figure out how to update the grid to allow me to use 1/3 and 1/2 columns.

It looks like with 1.0 you could just use:

```
<div class="span-one-third"></div>
```

Has anyone been able to figure out a way to do something similar with 2.0, or am I overlooking something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For newer versions (since v2), just use the span4 or col-xx-4 columns, since it is a 12 column grid.

For bootstrap 2:

```
<div class="span4"></div>
```

For bootstrap 3 (example):

```
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
```

**ORIGINAL AND OUTDATED ANSWER**

Just to make clear, this answer was to maintain the compatibility to applications that had the HTML using Bootstrap v1, that didn't have any responsive stuff and where the grid was 16 columns (when they changed that, some projects that already used v1 started using the new v2 version costumized with 16 columns). And they actually had .span-one-third, etc, css classes.

Just implement the old values from the bootstrap v1 css (with grid 16), as v2 doesn't implement it anymore.

```
.span-one-third{width:300px;}
.span-two-thirds{width:620px;}
.offset-one-third{margin-left:340px;}
.offset-two-thirds{margin-left:660px;}
```

And now u can still have the span-one-third and span-two-thirds classes. This was extracted from Bootstrap code: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v1.3.0/lib/scaffolding.less#L133

Comment: For anyone visiting this, it's important to know NOT to use this code. It will break the responsive styles and it's not correct today, nor was it correct when it was suggested.

Comment: Instead of just saying it is wrong, why not offer an alternative solution to the problem? You can edit the answer.

Comment: Yes, it won't work with responsive styles, but it is possible to do that working with responsive styles too, just add the % values along with the fluid row class. The code was just meant to help him keep his app running without breaking when updating bootstrap from 1.0 to 2.0. I don't think that's wrong, but indeed it misses the responsive values. It was the old values, and as he stated: "I created a custom grid". It works fine for people who updates from 1.0 to >2.0 and used 16 grid system on their apps, since it isn't implemented anymore.

Answer (score 20):

The reason Bootstrap used to include span-one-third is that the grid used 16 columns. Today, Bootstrap's grid includes 12 column's (spans) by default. So assuming you haven't customized the grid to use a different number of columns just use the following:

```
<!-- 3-columns, 1/3 each -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">1/3 width</div>
  <div class="span4">1/3 width</div>
  <div class="span4">1/3 width</div> 
</div>  

<!-- 2-columns, 1/2 each -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">1/2 width</div>
  <div class="span6">1/2 width</div>
</div>
```